# How to COALESCE for empty strings and NULL values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, coalesce

I'm trying to make the fastest COALESCE() that accepts two or more arguments, and returns the first non-null AND non-empty ("") value.

I'm using this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION coalescenonempty(VARIADIC in_ordered_actual varchar[])
RETURNS varchar AS $$
  SELECT i
  FROM (SELECT unnest($1) AS i) t
  WHERE i IS NOT NULL AND i <> ''
  LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

It's pretty fast, but still nowhere as fast as COALESCE or CASE WHEN statements.

What do you think?

Comment: Don't worry about "fastest" until you get "working" - even though there is working here, keep the question open and let the answers/suggestions come in. (And maybe the "better solution" is simply to not allow empty strings in the model ;-)

Comment: I agree with user2864740: if you want to prevent null and empty strings, why not disallow to put them into the database in the first place.

Answer (score 176):

Do not create a user function is you want speed. Instead of this:

```
coalescenonempty(col1,col2||'blah',col3,'none');
```

do this:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(col1,''),NULLIF(col2||'blah',''),NULLIF(col3,''),'none');
```

That is, for each non-constant parameter, surround the actual parameter with `NULLIF( x ,'')`.

Comment: Coalesce is not defined it is coming, You have any idea about this ??