# postgres - avoid creating duplicate null columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have this table schema on Postgres:

```
> \d+ users_types_brands

                   Table "public.users_types_brands"
     Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                    Default                     | Storage | Stats target | Description 
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id             | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('users_types_brands_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              | 
 inserted_at    | timestamp without time zone |           |          | now()                                          | plain   |              | 
 updated_at     | timestamp without time zone |           |          | now()                                          | plain   |              | 
 users_types_id | bigint                      |           |          |                                                | plain   |              | 
 brand_id       | bigint                      |           | not null |                                                | plain   |              | 
 tasks_type_id  | integer                     |           |          |                                                | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "users_types_brands_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "users_types_brands_users_types_id_brand_id_tasks_type_id_index" UNIQUE, btree (users_types_id, brand_id, tasks_type_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "users_types_brands_users_types_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (users_types_id) REFERENCES users_types(id)
Access method: heap
```

Right now the table looks like this:

```
my_db=# select * from users_types_brands;
 id |        inserted_at         |         updated_at         | users_types_id | brand_id | tasks_type_id 
----+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------+----------+---------------
 12 | 2021-10-24 16:43:12.244026 | 2021-10-24 16:43:12.244026 |              2 |      112 |             8
 14 | 2021-10-24 17:03:12.012874 | 2021-10-24 17:03:12.012874 |              2 |      111 |             9
(2 rows)
```

Of course, I can't insert a row like this:

```
my_db=# insert into users_types_brands (users_types_id, brand_id, tasks_type_id) values (2, 112, 8);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_types_brands_users_types_id_brand_id_tasks_type_id_index"
DETAIL:  Key (users_types_id, brand_id, tasks_type_id)=(2, 112, 8) already exists.
```

But I can do this several times:

```
my_db=# insert into users_types_brands (users_types_id, brand_id) values (2, 112);
INSERT 0 1
```

**And obtain this:**

```
my_db=# select * from users_types_brands;
 id |        inserted_at         |         updated_at         | users_types_id | brand_id | tasks_type_id 
----+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------+----------+---------------
 12 | 2021-10-24 16:43:12.244026 | 2021-10-24 16:43:12.244026 |              2 |      112 |             8
 14 | 2021-10-24 17:03:12.012874 | 2021-10-24 17:03:12.012874 |              2 |      111 |             9
 16 | 2021-10-24 17:15:58.295428 | 2021-10-24 17:15:58.295428 |              2 |      112 |              
 17 | 2021-10-24 17:16:36.99971  | 2021-10-24 17:16:36.99971  |              2 |      112 |              
(4 rows)
```

Now, according to the business rules, **`tasks_type_id` can be null**

**But how can I avoid creating repeated rows like the last two? One null `tasks_type_id` is OK, but not two or more.**

Has anyone faced this before?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393182/how-to-coalesce-for-empty-strings-and-null-values) can answer to your question

Comment: Well, not exactly. According to the docs:
`The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null. It is often used to substitute a default value for null values when data is retrieved for display`.
**But what I'm looking for is to not create the record**
Thank you, though 

Comment: oh ok. And maybe you can use `GROUP BY tasks_type_id` if you are sure that other `tasks_type_id` will appear one time

Comment: in the unique index, you can use coalesce to convert the nulls to -1 or some other non used valid value to prevent duplicate nulls
like : CREATE UNIQUE INDEX X ON Y ( ( COALESCE( nullable_field, -1 ) ), other_field );

Comment: @ncank yes, it solves it. **How could I mark this as correct?** BTW, I did this this way for my case `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY users_types_brands_users_types_id_brand_id_tasks_type_id_index ON users_types_brands (users_types_id, brand_id, COALESCE(tasks_type_id, -1));`

Thanks, @Elikill58

Comment: glad it worked out. adding an answer so you can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic solutions to this problem but both have their own cons.

1.Using a partial index, as Belayer pointed out. The downside is for non-null values you will require another partial index since this one will ignore non-null values and cover only the rows with nulls.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_for_nulls" ON "table" ( "field_a", "field_b" ) WHERE "field_c" IS NULL;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_for_non_nulls" ON "table" ( "field_a", "field_b", "field_c" ) WHERE "field_c" IS NOT NULL;
```

2.Using COALESCE in the index definition to avoid null values. This way index will cover all rows but planner won't use the full index if you don't use the exact statement which is defined in the index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index" ON "table" ( "field_a", "field_b", ( COALESCE( "field_c", -1 ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [Partial Unique Index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-partial.html). It will allow a *single row* with the same users_types_id and brand_id and null tasks_type_id, but only a single one.  (See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=81190af0d215501c3fe2e54e5bdd1a07))

```
create unique index tasks_type_id_just_1_unique
    on users_types_brands (users_types_id, brand_id)
  where tasks_type_id is null;
```